# SoapUI assertions Illegal unquoted character

Tags: soapui, assertions

I'm testing a rest api with soap but when the json that is input is not formatted well (quote missing per example) it returns the following error:

> Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value

Which is normal nevertheless it returns code 200 so I can't know if there is an error.

How can I control this error with assertions?

Comment: Can you post the message you're asserting against?

Comment: edit and add a screenshot to explain better.. Whats the entrance ?

Comment: So if I understand correctly you are sending a request with invalid JSON. And response for such request still return status code 200? Does it by any chance return some HTML site/page with error when this happens? Cause it really depends how the API is implemented for such error handling scenario. Anyway, just as others pointed out, provide screenshot from SOAPUI or at least some text request/response and maybe someone can help then :-).